# How to call sp_help [table] for SQL Server when using Oracle SQL Developer as my client

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, sql-server-2005

I am using Oracle SQL Developer in a linux environment to connect to an SQL Server 2005.

I don't seem to be able to make a sp_help [table_name] call. Previously, I found it quite useful when I was on a Windows environment using SQL Server management, and could make that call.

Is there any way to do this?

[edit] error message returned is the following:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
sp_help city
Error report:
Unknown Command
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered using the information_schema views instead. 
E.g.

```sql
Select *
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'City'
```

Comment: Oooh, that's pretty neat. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `exec sp_helptable [table_name]`?

Comment: exec sp_help [table_name]? or exec sp_helptable [table_name]?
Well, I tried both, and none worked...

Answer (score 2):

this works: `exec sp_helptable 'table_name'`

Comment: this syntax works as expected by the above person...which gives the entire schema details of the table mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say this, but SQL Server won't care about the string it's sent in the batch so it's problem with the client or the driver.

If you have to use Linux, try [SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) instead which is a vey nice tool

Comment: Maybe I should go with SQuirreL. I only recently moved to linux for my dev environment, and was just getting comfortable with Oracle SQL Develper.

Answer (score 0):

`exec sp_help [db.schema.table]` works